# AWS NACL is not working for EKS kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-ec2, amazon-eks

I am trying to block few malicious IPs from accessing my EKS cluster's EC2 instances.
To test this, I am adding Deny rule for my IP in the NACL, but I am still able to open the web server.

I have verified my IP by creating an EC2 and blocking SSH and i was able to block myself.
But in case of EKS NACl, its not working.
I am able to block all traffic by creating deny rule for 0.0.0.0/0 . But I'm unable to block particular IPs.

Anyone has come across this and knows why this could be happening?

Comment: Is the ACL applied to all subnets the cluster operates in? Is the ACL applied to the subnet in which the Load Balancer resides if one exists?

Comment: Yes . ACL is applied to all subnets(3 private and 3 public subnets). the load balancer resides in public subnets and ACL is attached to those